# Linq to Object -Object update

Tags: c#, linq

In `LINQ to Object` context ,can i update an object in memory.

I mean i can create new type like

```
var query =from e in empList
           select new {id=e.id,salary=e.salary * (10/100) };
```

can i update an object?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Anonymous types are immutable.  If the type is not anonymous, you can dump the collection to a List and modify that:

```
(from e in empList)
.ToList()
.ForEach(e => {
    e.salary = 999;
})
;
```

Notice I'm using block syntax in the lambda.

Comment: However, this will be slower than a `foreach` loop.  (Because of the `ToList` call)

Comment: And, all things being equal, a lambda expression will be slower (to invoke, though not to execute) than normal procedural code. Lambdas are a good idea when they make the code more readable or concise, but I don't see how this is particularly more readable or concise than a simple `foreach` statement.

Comment: I use LINQPad for a lot of misc tasks involving hundreds of thousands of records.  In my experience the ToList() call is negligible compared to other bottlenecks.

Comment: .AsParallel()
.ForAll(x => { e.salary = 999; })
;

Is NOT slower than a foreach loop in .NET 4 btw

Comment: @ifwdev: That's certainly not true as an absolute statement. Execute that on a single-core processor and you're needlessly splitting the list into multiple threads to no advantage.

Comment: Why would it split into multiple threads if there is only one core available?

But yes, you are right, it's not true as an absolute statement.  In the scenarios where there is any significant performance overhead from calling ToList, I'd think AsParallel would make up for it though.

Answer (score 4):

No; you need to use a `foreach` loop.

Comment: This is correct, the foreach loop is designed to operated over an Enumerable... you can even use a for loop

LINQ was designed to QUERY collections, not iterate over them

Comment: He can't modify the objects created in his example. Anonymous types are immutable.

Comment: I don't think he meant to use an anonymous type at all

Answer (score 4):

That depends on what you're asking.

If you're asking: **Can I use a LINQ statement to update data on the elements of a collection?** Then the answer is simply no; LINQ is a query language, not a data modification language. Just use a `foreach` loop on the original collection as you would have done prior to .NET 3.5/C# 3.0. Nothing to see here.

If you're asking **Can I update the values on the type I created in the query in my question?**, then the answer is "sortof". The type you're creating by using `new { ... }` is an anonymous type, which makes it immutable (read only). There's no clean way to do what you're after, but you could do something like:

```
var query = from e in empList
            select new { id = e.id, salary = e.salary / 10.0, record = e }
```

Doing this will give you a reference to the original object via the `record` property, which you can change values on. Realize, though, that the values on your anonymous type (`id` and `salary`, in this case) will not reflect any changes made to the referenced object in `record`.

```
foreach(var element in empList)
{
    element.record.salary = 100.0;
}
```

This will update the salary property on the original item, but `element.salary` will still reflect the original value that was calculated in the query, *not* the new salary value `/ 10.0`.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, that will work just fine.

Note, however, that the object you are create, while looking like and having the same properties as an Emp, will be a distinct object type.

To elaborate, if you were to say:

```
var query =from e in empList 
select e;
```

You are creating a collection of Emp objects.   When you say:

```
var query =from e in empList    
select new {id=e.id,salary=e.salary * (10/100) };
```

You are creating a collection of anonomous objects which have the same form as Emp objects.  You can assign values which may be different from the original empList value, while you are creating it, but once that statement is complete, thosee values cannot be changed again. And nothing here will affect the values in empList.

Comment: No, it won't; anonymous types are immutable.